# Problem unistalling ubuntu 13.10 from bootloader(windows 8)

Tags: usb, windows, uninstall, bootloader

I installed ubuntu 13.10 on my usb. Then I formatted the usb with ubuntu 13.10, but now how to remove the ubuntu from boot loader on windows 8.  I was trying to install ubuntu 14.10 on my hard disk but it says "a previous installation of ubuntu was found on C:/" although I had formatted the usb and there is no ubuntu folder in C drive. How to remove it from boot loader because I think it would be causing problem?

Comment: Question is unclear. Try to elaborate.

Comment: I dual booted my pc with ubuntu 13.10 and windows 8. Ubuntu was installed on a usb [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) I formatted the usb on windows 8. Now how to remove the ubuntu icon from the boot screen. There are two icons for dual boot still there 1) for windows 8 and 2) for Ubuntu

Comment: When adding more detail to your question please add it in the body of your question. Comments can and do get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EasyBcd to remove the Ubuntu Entry.

There's a Payware version and a Freware one.  --- http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/#comparison

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Comment: I used easyBCD and removed the boot entries(ubuntu). Now its not appearing at booting time.

Comment: But during installation of ubuntu I'm getting the same error "Previous installation found at C:/ , Please unintall it". What to do now ?

Comment: You installed ubuntu on your USB and made the mistake to install grub on the C drive instead on the USB. Well now you need to download CCleaner and do a registry clean and see if it does the trick.  -- https://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER